# GCE Kubernetes and Load Balancer http to https

Tags: load-balancing, google-cloud-platform, ingress

I have hired a DevOps to setup my infrastructure on GCE.  We have decided to use Kubernetes Engine for our App.  My DevOps has setup multiple load balancers and is using ingress.  The issue is that he is now telling me that we need cloudfare to handle the redirect from http to https.  I find this bizarre that GCE would not have solved this with its Load Balancer.  Also can a single Load Balancer handle multiple applications and domains and why would we need multiple?

Answer (score 0):

GKE ingress uses GCE LB. GCE L7LB does not handle HTTP to HTTPS redirects so this is also applicable for [GKE ingress](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer). Users may configure their own HTTP to HTTPS redirect within the pod (customer's container config) .

Yes, a single Ingress can handle multiple domains just like GCE LB can handle multiple URL maps. Backend services direct traffic to the backends that host multiple applications and domains based on the URL maps( host and path rule) defined.